# gnu screen get user@host on hardline

Tags: gnu-screen

I create screen session with

```
ssh user1@host1, user2@host1, ..., user5@host1.
```

On hardline I see only host1 five times. The same when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>".

How can I define a hardline to get `user1@host1, ..., user5@host1` on it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already had a look at your `~/.screenrc`? This file defines what screen writes to your status lines. Thus, in your current configuration you'll probably find something like that:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline "[...]%H[...]"
```

which displays the host name in your `hardstatus` line (see [STRING ESCAPES of the man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/screen1.html)). To also display the user name replace the line in your configuration with something like:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline "[...]$USER@%H[...]"
```

you can also have a look at [my configuration](http://binfalse.de/software/conf-rc/screen-rc/).